# How to display certain content underneath another block of content

Tags: html, css

I have a screenshot below where it displays exam information, a timer and some questions:

[image]

Now the issue is that I want the Question details to be displayed underneath the exam details, not next it. My question is how can I get the questions to be displayed underneath? I want the questions beneath one another as well

**HTML/PHP:**

```
//EXAM DETAILS
 <div class='lt-container'>

    <p><input type='hidden' id='studentId' name='studentId' value='<?php echo $dbStudentId; ?>' /></p>
    <p><strong>Student:</strong><?php echo $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname; ?> <br/>
    <strong>Module:</strong><?php echo $dbModuleNo . " - " . $dbModuleName; ?> 
    <input type='hidden' id='moduleId' name='moduleId' value='<?php echo $dbModuleId; ?>' /><br/>
    <strong>Assessment:</strong><?php echo $dbSessionName . " - " . date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . " - " . date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime)); ?> 
    <input type='hidden' id='sessionId' name='sessionId' value='<?php echo $dbSessionId; ?>' /><br/>
    <strong>Assessment Weight: </strong><?php echo $dbSessionWeight; ?> <br/>
    <strong>Total Marks: </strong><?php echo $dbTotalMarks; ?> <br/>
    <strong>Penalty: </strong><?php echo $penaltymsg; ?> </p>
    </div>

//TIMER
    <div id='rt-container'>
    <h1><span id='countdown'><?php echo $dbSessionDuration; ?></span></h1>
    </div>

    <?php
    }

//QUESTION DETAILS
    foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

    ?>

    <div class='lt-container'>
    <p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"></span>:</strong></p>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.lt-container{
 float: left;   
 }

#rt-container {
 clear: right;
 float:right;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from the `.lt-container`. And place the `#rt-container` above the `.lt-container`

```
.lt-container{   
 }
#rt-container {
 float:right;  
    background:red
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XnACL/)**

Answer (score 0):

you are using float right in your css which is forcing the div to float right.
What you can do is give the width 100% to your left div which will shift your right div at bottom of left div.